# Looking for multi step form in Drupal that can also show submissions in Admin

Tags: forms

I hope I am not offending someone with this naive question.

I am currently trying to create a customized JQuery + PHP + HTML multi step form in Drupal. I am hoping if anyone of you could let me know if there is some way I can create this and also see the submissions through Admin.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), possibly with [Steps](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps)? Have you tried any of contrib modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module and [Webform steps](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps) module to visualize the steps.

The process is as follows:

- Create Webform put some fields organized in Fieldsets if you like.
- To make new page insert pagebreak

[image: sample printscr].

If you want more customization you can follow [this tutorial](http://envisioninteractive.com/web-development/breaking-drupal-7-webforms-into-multiple-steps-the-easy-way/) for creating your own module for that.

Comment: 10x @Mołot for the edit I start to answer this before your comment come out if you like remove my answer altogether if your privileges allow it

Comment: Leave your answer in place. After all you put your time and effort to put it together, so you deserve reputation from it.

Comment: Thank you Molot and NexusStar! I did exactly that and also adding Webform AJAX Module. That gave me exactly what I needed.